# Insert data from csv to postgreSQL database via Python

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, csv

I'm brand new to postgreSQL or SQL at all. 
I'm trying to create a table in a database via Python and then load data from a .csv file into the table. 
My code looks like this:

```
import csv
import psycopg2

#Establish connection to database 
con = psycopg2.connect(
        host = "localhost",
        database = "kundeavgang",
        user = "postgres",
        password = "postgres",
        )

#Cursor 
cur = con.cursor()

#If a mistake is made, start from scratch
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kundeavgang")

#Create table
cur.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE "kundeavgang"(
            "customerID" TEXT,
            "gender" TEXT,
            "SeniorCitizen" TEXT,
            "Partner" TEXT,
            "Dependents" TEXT,
            "tenure" INT,
            "PhoneService" TEXT,
            "MultipleLines" TEXT,
            "InternetService" TEXT,
            "OnlineSecurity" TEXT,
            "DeviceProtection" TEXT,
            "TechSupport" TEXT,
            "StreamingMovies" TEXT,
            "Contract" TEXT,
            "PaperlessBilling" TEXT,
            "PaymentMethod" TEXT,
            "MonthlyCharges" FLOAT,
            "TotalCharges" FLOAT,
            "Churn" TEXT
            )
            ''')

#Acsess .csv file
with open('kundeavgang.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    skipHeader = next(reader) #Account for header
    for row in reader: 
        customerID = row[0]
        gender = row[1]
        SeniorCitizen = row[2]
        Partner = row[3]
        Dependents = row[4]
        tenure = row[5]
        PhoneService = row[6]
        MultipleLines = row[7]
        InternetService = row[8]
        OnlineSecurity = row[9]
        OnlineBackup = row[10]
        DeviceProtection = row[11]
        TechSupport = row[12]
        StreamingTV = [13]
        StreamingMovies = row[14]
        Contract = row[15]
        PaperlessBilling = row[16]
        PaymentMethod = row[17]
        MonthlyCharges = row[18]
        TotalCharges = row[19]
        Churn = row[20]
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO kundeavgang(customerID,gender,SeniorCitizen,Partner,Dependents,tenure,PhoneService,MultipleLines,InternetService,OnlineSecurity,OnlineBackup,DeviceProtection,TechSupport,StreamingTV,StreamingMovies,Contract,PaperlessBilling,PaymentMethod,TotalCharges,Churn)
            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(customerID,gender,SeniorCitizen,Partner,Dependents,tenure,PhoneService,MultipleLines,InternetService,OnlineSecurity,OnlineBackup,DeviceProtection,TechSupport,StreamingTV,StreamingMovies,Contract,PaperlessBilling,PaymentMethod,TotalCharges,Churn))


#Commit the transaction
con.commit()

#End connection
con.close()
```

In pgAdmin, the table comes up as existing in the database. However, I cannot find the actual table. Further, I have no idea about this line of code:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO kundeavgang(customerID,gender,SeniorCitizen,Partner,Dependents,tenure,PhoneService,MultipleLines,InternetService,OnlineSecurity,OnlineBackup,DeviceProtection,TechSupport,StreamingTV,StreamingMovies,Contract,PaperlessBilling,PaymentMethod,TotalCharges,Churn)
            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(customerID,gender,SeniorCitizen,Partner,Dependents,tenure,PhoneService,MultipleLines,InternetService,OnlineSecurity,OnlineBackup,DeviceProtection,TechSupport,StreamingTV,StreamingMovies,Contract,PaperlessBilling,PaymentMethod,TotalCharges,Churn))
```

What does all the %s stand for? I found it off an online example which was not very helpful, so I tried it without knowing what it means. I have seen some examples where question marks are inserted instead, but also this without explanation.

Lastly, as the code stands now, I get the error message:

```
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(customerID,gender,SeniorCitizen,Partner,Dependents,tenure,PhoneService,MultipleLines,InternetService,OnlineSecurity,OnlineBackup,DeviceProtection,TechSupport,StreamingTV,StreamingMovies,Contract,PaperlessBilling,PaymentMethod,TotalCharges,Churn))
```

IndexError: tuple index out of range

All help or explanations will be appreciated.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Could you please elaborate on what that means? Or how I can get the actual data that I want into the SQL instead of 22 %s?

Comment: Why don't you use [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html) and bypass reading data into Python?

Comment: Your `row` list has 21 elements, but your values clause contains 22 %s placeholders.  They need to match.

Comment: @Parfait : Trying to develop my python knowlegde while I'm at it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bulk inserts from text files, consider [**`copy_from`**](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) or [**`copy_expert`**](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) of `psycopg2`. Also, be sure to commit your execution:

```
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kundeavgang")
con.commit()

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE "kundeavgang" ... ''')
con.commit()

with open('kundeavgang.csv') as csvFile:
   next(csvFile) # SKIP HEADERS
   cur.copy_from(csvFile, "kundeavgang", sep=",")

   # POSTGRES COPY COMMAND FOR CSV MODE
   # cur.copy_expert("""COPY "kundeavgang" FROM STDIN WITH CSV""", csvFile)
   con.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` are placeholders for the values that will be inserted and passed through the following tuple:

```
(customerID,gender,SeniorCitizen,Partner,Dependents,tenure,PhoneService,MultipleLines,InternetService,OnlineSecurity,OnlineBackup,DeviceProtection,TechSupport,StreamingTV,StreamingMovies,Contract,PaperlessBilling,PaymentMethod,TotalCharges,Churn)
```

The problem that your insert statement going to insert to 20 columns, you provide 20 values in your tuple but you have 22 placeholders (`%s`).

Comment: Okay, does %s hold every data type? Further, with the row[0] index I have a total of 21. When reducing to 21 placeholders I get a new error message: 

 VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(customerID,gender,SeniorCitizen,Partner,Dependents,tenure,PhoneService,MultipleLines,InternetService,OnlineSecurity,OnlineBackup,DeviceProtection,TechSupport,StreamingTV,StreamingMovies,Contract,PaperlessBilling,PaymentMethod,TotalCharges,Churn))

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `%s` should be used for all datatypes. Take a look here: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: @Aleks you have 20 values in your tuple

Comment: In which line do you get the error? This error indicates that you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist in your tuple. Please make sure that the numbers of columns in your insert statement, the number of placeholders and the number of values in the tuple provided for the placeholder are equal. In addition, you defined 21 variables (access 0-20 indices) but you have only 20 columns in your statement. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a mismatch between the number of columns to be populated and the length of the list provided.  This is an easy mistake to make when dealing with a lot of columns.  One way to reduce risk of error is to use the length of the columns or values list to build the statement.

```
cols = [name1, name2,...]
vals = [val1, val2, ...]
assert len(cols) == len(vals), 'mismatch between number of columns and number of values'
template = """INSERT INTO tbl ({}) VALUES ({})"""
stmt = template.format(', '.join(cols), ','.join(['%s'] * len(vals)))
cur.execute(stmt, vals)
```

Note that when building the column names dynamically it's good practice to quote them - psycopg2 provides [tools](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html?highlight=quote#module-psycopg2.sql) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `reader = csv.reader(csvFile)` to:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).